# How to convert complex JavaScript arrays to a combined array and loop to a table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I stuck in combining two arrays with objects inside and reassign the values in a standard format. Can someone offer some guidance? Thanks.

My case now:

```
array1 = [{Apple: Ken,  Orange: Mary, Melon: Tina, Strawberry: Jessica, Mango: Susana, Lemon: Julia}]
array2 = [{Apple: 12,  Orange: 6, Melon: 7, Strawberry: 16, Mango: 15, Lemon: 11}]
```

Intended outcome:

```
arrayCombined = [[Apple: Ken, 12],[Orange: Mary, 6], [Melon: Tina, 7], [Strawberry: Jessica, 16], [Mango: Susana, 15], [Lemon: Julia, 11]]
```

Intended display in the table:

```
Fruit      | Fruit(buyer)  | Fruit(number of purchase) | even-number prize
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Apple      |   Ken         |     12                    |     Yes        
Orange     |   Mary        |      6                    |     Yes  
Melon      |   Tina        |      7                    |      No  
Strawberry |   Jessica     |     16                    |     Yes  
Mango      |   Susana      |     15                    |      No  
Lemon      |   Julia       |     11                    |      No
```

Comment: `[Apple: Ken, 12]` this is not valid javascript syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well assuming that your data has a valid format like this:

```
const array1 = [{Apple: 'Ken',  Orange: 'Mary', Melon: 'Tina', Strawberry: 'Jessica', Mango: 'Susana', Lemon: 'Julia'}]
const array2 = [{Apple: 12,  Orange: 6, Melon: 7, Strawberry: 16, Mango: 15, Lemon: 11}]
```

You can use `Object.entries()` to get an array of arrays that contains a `key - value` of the first array, then you can `map` that array so that you compute the 'combined array' as something with a certain valid format, here is my suggestion:

```js
const array1 = [{Apple: 'Ken',  Orange: 'Mary', Melon: 'Tina', Strawberry: 'Jessica', Mango: 'Susana', Lemon: 'Julia'}]
const array2 = [{Apple: 12,  Orange: 6, Melon: 7, Strawberry: 16, Mango: 15, Lemon: 11}]

const arrayCombined = Object.entries(array1[0])
  .map(([fruit, person]) => {
    const count = array2[0][fruit];

    return { [fruit]: [person, count] };
  })

console.log(arrayCombined);
```